# Commutative Lie group: Image of maximal compact subgroup contains the connected component of the identity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

I have a question about Lie groups, ie we have the follwoing situation:
Suppose we have a surjective lie group homonorphism $ X \rightarrow A$ (in particular, A is the group $A(k)$, where A is an abelian variety over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and $X$ is a smooth commutative group scheme of finite type over the field and we Look at $X(k)$). Let $X^1$ be the maximal compact subgroup of $X$.
We want to show that $X^1 \rightarrow A$ is surjective. They claim that the Image of $X^1$ contains the connected component of A of the Identity and this will do the job. My problem is to see why this claim is true, more concretely I need that $A/Image(X^1)$ is finite.
Has Someone an idea? First idea: the connected component of the identity is generated by the image of the exponential map and we know that since $X \rightarrow A$ is surjective the map between the Lie algebras is surjective. (A as an abelian variety is connected)
Let $X^0$ be the connected component of the identity of $X$. So $A^0=Image(X^0)$. If we can show that $X^0 \subset  X^1$ we are done. But is this true?

Thanks for any comments.